# function within a loop within a function?

Tags: function, for-loop, counter

I'm coding an email verification form in 3 parts.

Part 1 - check a single character against a list of allowed characters and return true/false.

Part 2 - check a string of characters as the part before or after the '@' using a loop calling the previous function to each successive character.

Part 3 - check a complete email that it includes only one '@', the substring before and after the '@' both satisfy part 2 and the substring following the '@' has only one full stop.

I've got part 1 down but my loop for part 2 is incorrect and returning true for all input values other than a blank form. here is the code -

```
        function isValidEmailPart(part)
        {   var emailPartInput = document.getElementById("isValidPartArg").value;
    var emailPartLength = alert(emailPartInput.length);
    {
    if (emailPartInput.length == "")
      {
      return (false)
      }
      else
      {
    NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS = alert((emailPartInput.length) - 1);
    var i = 0;
      {for(var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS; i++)
        {
        function isValidEmailChar()
          { var validChars = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,_,-,.,';
            var emailPartInput = document.getElementById("isValidPartArg").value;
            var charInput = emailPartInput.charAt(i);
            var inputVar = validChars.indexOf(charInput);
            if (inputVar < 0)
            {
            return (false)
            }
          }
        }
        return (true);
      }
      }
    }
     }
```

I know it must be something simple, there are no errors returning I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Mate I think you have a lots of mistakes in your code :S...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, there are no errors when I run it in my browser.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what `emailPartInput` could be?

Comment: it could be any combination of letters, numbers or other characters. eg kojg1342 should return true
eg ikgkjn><9 should return false

Comment: But i mean, does `emailPartInput` include the character `@`? Could it be `hello@gmail.com` for instance? Or do you mean that `emailPartInput` is the first part of the email, before the `@`, so: `hello`, considering the previous example.

Comment: it should be any section before or after but not including the @, so hello OR gmail.com

Comment: Ok I understand what you want. Now, just one last question... Is it a homework?

Comment: it is, yes. although I should stress that I don't want someone to give me a replacement code that serves the same purpose. I just need help to work out why the loop is returning a true value even for characters that should return false. is the loop counter not working? or is it maybe because the charAt(i) is simple checking the letter 'i' within the var validChars?

Comment: Ok so I'll include some pieces of advice and things you'll have to review. Please give me some secs mate...

Comment: I've just posted an answer. I took some time to answer your question and I tried to provide a good answer. I hope this will help you. I suggest that you try to finding your mistakes before reading my code.

Answer (score 1):

Please, consider the following things very carefully:

- **Define functions separately:** you can call a function from another function BUT **don't define a function inside a function**
- **Make sure that your code is ok, pay attention to your code syntax:** I found additional `{` for example. Usually your code editor highlights code syntax errors.
- **Pay attention to your code's indent:** having a good indent helps you have a clearer view of your code and helps you find your potential code mistakes.
- **Review the different types of variables:** in javascript, the variables can have different types: boolean, integer, float, string, etc. You can only compare variables of a same types (Do not mix carrots and potatoes!) and so, you cannot compare `emailPartInput` with an empty string `""` for example.
- **Before reading the code bellow, you should try to search what was wrong it your code, and what has to be modified to make it work.**
- **Check very carefully the comments I wrote in the code that follows (I took a lot of time to write them!)**

---

**The javascript functions:**

```
// This functions verifies if a char 'my_char' is valid
function isValidEmailChar(my_char)
{ 
    // 'my_char' is a i-th character of 'emailPartInput'
    var output = false;

    // 'validChars' is the array containing all the valid characters
    var validChars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
                      'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
                      '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','_','-','.'];

    // We want to check if 'my_char' is in the array 'validChar'
    // So, for each character in the array 'validChar', we check that there's at least
    //  1 character in it which is equal to 'my_char'
    for(var i=0; i<validChars.length; i++)
    {
        // 'output' is the result that the function 'isValidEmailChar' will return
        // It is initially set to "false"
        // The line below means: we store in 'output' 
        //   the result of " output OR ['my_char' EQUALS the i-th character in the array 'validChars'] ".
        //   Which means that, in the end, 'output' will be "true" if there's at least one i-th character 
        //      in the  array 'validChars' where 'my_char' EQUALS the i-th character in the array  'validChars'.
        output = (output || (my_char == validChars[i]));
    }

    // We return the output
    // Note: It is better to define 1 'return' and not several
    return output;
}

// This function verifies if a part of Email is valid
function isValidEmailPart(emailPartInput)
{   
    // 'emailPartInput' is the part of email

    // 'output' is your function's result to be returned
    var output = false;

    alert("INPUT = "+emailPartInput);

    var nb_of_characters = emailPartInput.length;       
    alert("number of characters = "+nb_of_characters);

    if (nb_of_characters != 0)
    {
        output = true;
        var i = 0;

        while(output && i<nb_of_characters)
        {
            // 'is_character_valid' is a boolean value which is set to:
            //     - true: if the i-th character of 'emailPartInput' is valid
            //     - false: if not valid
            var is_character_valid = isValidEmailChar(emailPartInput.charAt(i));

            // The line below means that we store in the variable 'ouput' the result of
            //    'output' AND 'is_character_valid', which means that:
            //        if there's at least one 'is_character_valid' set to false 
            //        (= one i-th character of 'emailPartInput' is not valid)
            //        'output' will then be equals to false
            output = output && is_character_valid;

            i++;

            // We remark that if 'output' is false, we quit the 'while' loop
            // because finding one invalid character means that 'emailPartInput' is invalid
            // so, we do not need to check the other characters of 'emailPartInput'
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("No emailPartInput has been input"); 
    }

    // We return the output
    return output;
}
```

---

**Here's a working example where you can test your functions:**

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">

        // This functions verifies if a char 'my_char' is valid
        function isValidEmailChar(my_char)
        { 
            // 'my_char' is a i-th character of 'emailPartInput'
            var output = false;

            // 'validChars' is the array containing all the valid characters
            var validChars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
                      'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
                      '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','_','-','.'];

            // We want to check if 'my_char' is in the array 'validChar'
            // So, for each character in the array 'validChar', we check that there's at least
            //  1 character in it which is equal to 'my_char'
            for(var i=0; i<validChars.length; i++)
            {
                // 'output' is the result that the function 'isValidEmailChar' will return
                // It is initially set to "false"
                // The line below means: we store in 'output' 
                //   the result of " output OR ['my_char' EQUALS the i-th character in the array 'validChars'] ".
                //   Which means that, in the end, 'output' will be "true" if there's at least one i-th character 
                //      in the  array 'validChars' where 'my_char' EQUALS the i-th character in the array  'validChars'.
                output = (output || (my_char == validChars[i]));
            }

            // We return the output
            // Note: It is better to define 1 'return' and not several
            return output;
        }

        // This function verifies if a part of Email is valid
        function isValidEmailPart(emailPartInput)
        {   
            // 'emailPartInput' is the part of email

            // 'output' is your function's result to be returned
            var output = false;

            alert("INPUT = "+emailPartInput);

            var nb_of_characters = emailPartInput.length;       
            alert("number of characters = "+nb_of_characters);

            if (nb_of_characters != 0)
            {
                output = true;
                var i = 0;

                while(output && i<nb_of_characters)
                {
                    // 'is_character_valid' is a boolean value which is set to:
                    //     - true: if the i-th character of 'emailPartInput' is valid
                    //     - false: if not valid
                    var is_character_valid = isValidEmailChar(emailPartInput.charAt(i));

                    // The line below means that we store in the variable 'ouput' the result of
                    //    'output' AND 'is_character_valid', which means that:
                    //        if there's at least one 'is_character_valid' set to false 
                    //        (= one i-th character of 'emailPartInput' is not valid)
                    //        'output' will then be equals to false
                    output = output && is_character_valid;

                    i++;

                    // We remark that if 'output' is false, we quit the 'while' loop
                    // because finding one invalid character means that 'emailPartInput' is invalid
                    // so, we do not need to check the other characters of 'emailPartInput'
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert("No emailPartInput has been input"); 
            }

            // We return the output
            return output;
        }

        function test() {
            var my_input = document.getElementById("my_input").value;

            var result = isValidEmailPart(my_input);

            if(result) 
                alert("The part of email is valid");
            else
                alert("The part of email is NOT valid");
        }

        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        Enter you Email part here:
        <INPUT type="text" id="my_input" value="" />
        <button onclick="javascript:test();">Check the Email part!</button>   
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**NB:** The most important is to make sure that you understand what you wrote in your code and what was wrong.

I think you know that just copying a working won't be a benefit for you.

If you read my code, I hope you spent your time to understand it and to read the comments carefully (I took a lot of time to write them! :S)

You can check free online tutorials to learn javascript too! :)

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask, I'll be glad to help.